# How can I install only one directory by Composer from the vendor/package? Or delete directories after installation?

Tags: php, yii, composer-php

Sorry my english isn't too good. So I have a problem with the composer. It is that I can select which directory I would like to install from a package, or after installation delete them.
For example:
"yiisoft/yii" this is the vendor/package. But I would like to install only the "yiisoft/yii/framework" directory. I don't like to keep the other directories. 
I still find what will be the best solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mess with the vendor directory. There are good reason to keep it all together in `vendors`. If you really need to have certain files available from another path, use symlinks.

For more information about this topic read this authoritative blog post about the [Composer Vendor Directory](https://igor.io/2013/09/04/composer-vendor-directory.html) by Igor Wiedler.

Alternatively you could copy the content somewhere else (and/or delete) with phing.

Comment: Yes, but there are unuseful files :). And I don't want them in my app. (And the Netbeans shows errors in that files...) and make extra sizes!

Can you give me more information or tutorial about phing? :) Where I should start to learn it :)

Comment: Phing has a good documentation. You can start fro phing website.

Answer (score 0):

When you install a software with composer, you install all the repository. If you want to delete unused folder, you can use a particular feature of composer. You can catch some events like post-install-cmd or post-update-cmd in this way:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": "Sensorario\\Communityii\\ComposerCommands::postInstall",
        "post-update-cmd": "Sensorario\\Communityii\\ComposerCommands::postUpdate"
    }
}
```

In the root folder of your project you have composer.json, you will also need to add a file in [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) standard:
    - composer.json
    - src/Sensorario/Communityii/ComposerCommands.php

And this file can be like this:

namespace Sensorario\Communityii;

```
class ComposerCommands
{
    public static function postUpdate()
    {
        // remove unused folders
        shell_exec('rm vendor/yiisoft/yii/demos/ ... ');
    }
}
```

This code will run after

```
$ composer update
```